# Como saber quando o computador irá desligar/reiniciar/hibernar/suspender no Delphi?

Tags: delphi, websocket, object-pascal

Eu tenho um sistema que trabalha com websocket no Delphi com mORMot, quando eu reinicio o PC ou quando desligo ele executa o OnClose e o OnDestroy e através disso consigo remover o callback do usuário que estava logado, mas quando eu mando hibernar ou suspender eu preciso fazer o mesmo para que o usuário não conste como logado.

Seria bom também eu avisar o usuário que o sistema será fechado antes dele reiniciar/desligar ou suspender/hibernar e se possível eu identificar que o computador está voltando da suspensão/hibernação pra poder registrá-lo novamente.

Eu achei este exemplo mas não consegui entender seu funcionamento e como ele é chamado:

Declaração:

```
private
  procedure Hiber(var pMsg: TWMPower); message WM_POWERBROADCAST;
```

Implementação:

```
procedure Tform.Hiber(var pMsg: TWMPower);
begin
   if (pMsg.PowerEvt = PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND) then
   begin
     // Hibernando
   end
   else if (pMsg.PowerEvt = PBT_APMRESUMESUSPEND) then
   begin
     // Retornando
   end;
   pMsg.result := 1;
end;
```

Comment: Cara, eu vou dar uma testada nisso ai, mas parece que ele meche com as notificações/mensagens do próprio windows. Costumo usar esse tipo de métodos em threads, quando preciso fazer alterações visuais. Esse código funciona para você ?

Comment: Eu não sei como esse procedimento seria chamado. Não consegui rodar ele. Mas seria algo nesse estilo mesmo.
Quando ele hibernar eu removo o callback, quando ele voltar eu registro de novo.

Comment: Veja isso: https://github.com/xn--nding-jua/PC_DIMMER/blob/master/Core/PowerButton.pas

Comment: Eu não estou entendendo é como esse procedimento é chamando.

Comment: Usando o exemplo que você postou: você declara ao sistema operacional que quando houver uma mensagem do tipo `WM_POWERBROADCAST` ele deverá chamar a procedure `Hiber` de seu aplicativo. Essa procedure deve ser criada com os parametros exigidos pela chamada. Isso é registrado em uma tabela do sistema que se encarrega de chama-lo todas as vezes que um evento desse tipo ocorrer.

Comment: Esse código que postei não está funcionando aqui.
Eu havia encontrado nesse link: http://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/86661-hiberna%C3%A7%C3%A3o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Eu estava declaram em outro formulário, coloquei no formulário principal e funcionou. Mas tive que fazer algumas alterações pois o **PBT_APMQUERYSUSPEND** não é mais suportado à partir do Windows Vista.

Ficou desta forma:

*Declaração:*

```
procedure Hiber(var pMessage: TMessage); message WM_POWERBROADCAST;
```

*Implementação:*

```
procedure TFrm.Hiber(var pMessage: TMessage);
begin
   if pMessage.Msg = WM_POWERBROADCAST then
   begin
      if (pMessage.WParam = PBT_APMQUERYSTANDBY) or
         (pMessage.WParam = PBT_APMSUSPEND) then
      begin
         // Hibernando
         pMessage.Result := 1;
      end
      else if (pMessage.WParam = PBT_APMRESUMECRITICAL) or
         (pMessage.WParam = PBT_APMRESUMESUSPEND) or
         (pMessage.WParam = PBT_APMRESUMESTANDBY) then
      begin
         // Voltando
      end;
   end;
end;
```